# Closed set as the set of unbounded points of a function?

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is saied to be bounded in $x_0$ if there exist positive $\epsilon$ and $M$, such that for all $x\in (x_0-\epsilon ,x_0+\epsilon)$ we have $|f(x)|<M$.

Let $E$ is an arbitrary closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to construct a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which that the set of all points that $f$ is not bounded on them is precisely $E$.

Comment: $E$ can't contain any interval. Do you agree?

Comment: @Heydari  Let $E=\{0\}$.  Then $f(x)=x^{-1}$ with $f(0)=0$ is unbounded precisely at the point(s) in $E$.  Generally if $E$ is an arbitrary closed set you can easily handle the complement: each component of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is an open interval $(a,b)$ and you can easily find a function bounded at each point of $(a,b)$ but with $a$ and $b$ points of unboundedness. That is just a start though.

Comment: bounded **at** $x_0$, not "in $x_0$" or "on $x_0$".

Comment: @BrianO Right!  And I prefer the phrase "*locally* bounded at $x_0$" myself.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson and OP: English prepositions are notoriously difficult :) Many idioms and special cases. But mathematical English is much less arbitrary, and here clearly "at" is the right word, anyway "in" and "on" are wrong ones.

Comment: Fowler's English Usage gives an example of a sentence that ends " to from out of up for."

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be any open set in $R$. We have $U=\cup V$ where $V$ is a family of pairwise-disjoint open intervals.  Define $f$ on $V$ as follows : (1)  $x\in v=R\to f(x)=0. $  (2) $x\in v=$ $(-\infty,a)\to$ $ f(x)=1/(x-a).  (3) x\in v=(b,\infty)\to f(x)=1/(x-b). $ (4) $x\in v=(a,b)\to$ $ f(x)=1/(x-a)+1/(x-b) . $ Then$f$ is locally bounded on $U$. Let $E=R\backslash U. $ For $x\in E\backslash Q$ let $f(x)=0$.For $x=p/q\in E\cap Q$,where $p\in Z, q\in Z^+ $  and $\gcd (p,q)=1$, let $f(x)=q.$ Now (I) it is easy to see that  $x\in int (E)\to f$ is not locally bounded at $x$ (because $F=int(E)\backslash Q$ is dense in $int (E)$ and $f$ is not locally bounded at any $y\in F$).  (II)$x\in E\backslash int(E)\to x\in  \bar U\cap E=\bar U \backslash U\to$ every open interval containing $x$ contains an end-point of some $v\in V\to f $ is not locally bounded at $x$.

Comment: A different way of writing this might be clearer:  Let $E$ be closed and nowhere dense.  Then do what user254665 suggests on each of the component intervals of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$.  Define $f(x)$ anyway you like on $E$, and $f$ is locally bounded exactly at the points in $E$.  Now if $E$ contains some intervals handle each separately the way suggested so that $f$ is unbounded at each point in the closed intervals.  That is essentially user254665's proof but stated less formally.

Comment: For which other subsets of $R$ ( besides closed ones ) does there exist such a function?

Comment: This is a characterization.  Easiest way to see this is to prove that the set of points at which an arbitrary  function is locally bounded is open.  So this proof demonstrates that any open set $U$ can be the set of points of local boundedness or, equivalently that any closed set $E$ can be the set of points of unboundedness.  (Make sure your proof includes the cases $U=\emptyset$ and $U=\mathbb{R}$.)